# How does Java VM deal with cache line and memory alignment in MT contexts?

Tags: java, caching, jvm, memory-alignment

As per subject, if in C/C++ is *easy* to find cache line size and deal with this issue whilst developing efficient MT code, how does Java VM deal with this?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally it doesn't.  You have to work this out for yourself.  If it really matters you may have to use JNI to get low level details about the system.

Java on the other hand makes writing MT application easy by supporting it in the language from the start.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very good chance that Java will start to deal with this as of Java 8.  [JEP 142](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/142) states:

> Memory contention occurs when two memory locations that are in use by two different cores end up on the same cache line and at least one of the cores is performing writes. For highly contended memory locations this can be a serious performance and scalability issue. The aim of this enhancement is to avoid memory contention between cores, at least on fields we can easily identify during development.

There's [evidence that this is actually happening](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2013-January/013631.html) and is not vaporware.